Suggestion on which constraint to adds to optimize Minizinc's model
I've recently started using Minizinc to solve this simple problem:
Problem definition:
I have grid of dimensions H and W of boolean variables. The only constraint is that if a variable is false then at least one of the adjacent variables (top, right, left, bottom, diagonals don't count) must be true. The goal is to minimize the number of true values in the grid.
My code:
include "globals.mzn";

int: H = 20;
int: W = 20;
array[1..H, 1..W] of var bool: grid;

% Objective
var int: totsum = sum(i in 1..H, j in 1..W)(grid[i, j]);

% If a variable is false then at least one of the adjacent ones must be true
constraint forall(i in 1..H, j in 1..W)(not(grid[i, j]) -> grid[max(1, i-1), j] \/ grid[min(i+1, H), j] \/ grid[i, max(1, j-1)] \/ grid[i, min(W, j+1)]);

% If a variable is true then there must be at least 1 false variable
constraint forall(i in 1..H, j in 1..W)(grid[i, j] -> not(grid[max(1, i-1), j] /\ grid[min(i+1, H), j] /\ grid[i, max(1, j-1)] /\ grid[i, min(W, j+1)]));

% Implied constraint: the sum of trues along the rows must be less than the length of the row since no optimal solution should display this behavior
constraint forall(i in 1..H)(sum(row(grid, i)) < H);

% Same for columns
constraint forall(j in 1..W)(sum(col(grid, j)) < W);

% It is not possible to have 3x3 patches of equal values
constraint forall(i in 1..H-2, j in 1..W-2)(not(all_equal(a in i..i+2, b in j..j+2)(grid[a, b])));

% Symmetric rows (1 and H, 2 and H-1 etc...) ordering to break symmetry
constraint symmetry_breaking_constraint(forall(i in 1..(H div 2))(lex_lesseq(row(grid, i), row(grid, H+1-i))));

% Same for columns
constraint symmetry_breaking_constraint(forall(j in 1..(W div 2))(lex_lesseq(col(grid, j), col(grid, W+1-j))));

% Trivial upper bound: This is the case where the grid has alternating columns of true and false
constraint totsum < H*(W div 2 + 1);

solve :: bool_search(grid, input_order, indomain_min, complete) minimize totsum;

My code works but it becomes very slow when both H and W are greater than 20. Since I want to solve it for H=32 and W=32 this is unfeasible. I tried to run it for 1 hour but Minizinc wasn't able to find the optimal solution. I'm using the OR-TOOLS solver.
I thought about what to add to the model to improve its speed, and the only thing I could think of was adding diagonal symmetry breaking; finding the diagonal is trivial on a square but I don't really have a good idea on how to compute it in the general case.
Any suggestions to improve my model? Thank you very much

If I have understood the statement of your problem and turned it round to placing the minimum possible number of true values in the array then it strikes me that for 0 based indexing setting true on rows and columns 1,4,7,10... with some tweaks to fine tune boundary conditions when H, W are not exact multiples of 3 ought to do it.

With the following stripped-down code, I am arriving at an intermediate result of totsum 227 for H = W = 32.
Solvers are OR Tools or CPLEX, both with 8 threads. The runtime was about six minutes. It helped to reduce the totsum range.
include "globals.mzn";

int: H = 32;
int: W = 32;
set of int: OuterRows = 0..H+1;
set of int: Rows = 1..H;
set of int: OuterCols = 0..W+1;
set of int: Cols = 1..W;

array[OuterRows, OuterCols] of var bool: grid;

% Objective
%  we are looking for a specific range
var 210 .. 230: totsum = sum(i in Rows, j in Cols)(grid[i, j]);

% outer grid frame is false
% it helps to avoid case distinctions
constraint forall(i in OuterRows, j in {0, W+1})
  (not grid[i, j]);
constraint forall(i in {0, H+1}, j in OuterCols)
  (not grid[i, j]);

% If a variable is false then at least one of the adjacent ones must be true
constraint forall(i in Rows, j in Cols)
  (not(grid[i, j]) -> grid[i-1, j] \/ grid[i+1, j] \/ grid[i, j-1] \/ grid[i, j+1]);

solve minimize totsum;

function string: g(Rows: i, Cols: j) =
  if fix(grid[i, j]) then " T " else " - " endif;
  
output ["\n\ntotsum \(totsum)\n\n"] 
++ ["    "] ++ [ format(2, j) ++ " " | j in Cols ]
++ [ if j == 1 then "\n" ++ format(2, i) ++ ": " else "" endif ++ g(i, j) | i in Rows, j in Cols ];


When I add the following constraint, the inner diagonal structure of the grid is enforced. This reduces the solution time to 3s.
% fix the inner grid to reduce the number of active decision variables
int: InnerMargin = 4;
set of int: InnerRows = InnerMargin..H-InnerMargin;
set of int: InnerCols = InnerMargin..W-InnerMargin;
constraint forall(i in InnerRows, j in InnerCols)
  (grid[i, j] == (((i + (2*j mod 5)) mod 5) == 0));



If you post if as a CSV format I can score it on my Excel spreadsheet. I suspect some of the boundary edges of this solution are much be better than what I have below. A hybrid of the two approaches could be better still. I'd suggest a brute force attack against the top 4 rows to see if you can find any improvement.

I can't beat 227 either (by hand). There is a chance that your solution might by swapping the top right corner to a knights move pair (ie 31,1 & 32,3 or 32,2 and 30,1) .  Bottom left line of three T's together might also have scope for optimising out. Your solution has fewer pairs of T's than mine but an identical T count. Mine has fewer T's around the edges as another heuristic I used was to minimise pieces on the edge (where at least one attack is automatically wasted - and in corners 2 lost).

This optimisation problem is linked to chessboard problems of placing pieces so that they do not interact. Using this approach I noticed that the aim is to place every piece so that it occupies one square and controls exactly 4 more resulting in a decrease of 5 squares from the total free squares per piece.
With this heuristic it is obvious that by making a knights move the pieces can be placed so that in an infinite universe they would tile perfectly. It then remains to fix up the finite boundary conditions.
For 32x32 I can put a firm lower bound of 1024/5 ~ 205. My human generated pattern achieves 230 by placing all the pieces with the knights move rule so that on any line or column there are 4 gaps between each piece. The boundary edge fixup is crude - simply place a piece on any remaining zeroes. I think it may be possible to do a bit better by moving the fixup in from the very edge but I haven't been able to find any further improvement by hand.
Whilst writing this post I noticed that deleting (1,30) and (1,32) and replacing it with one on (1,31) reduces the number of "T"s to 229. I suspect further improvements may be possible by brute force optimisation of the edge three rows.
The histogram of my solution for neighbouring "T"s is:
 0: 0
 1: 951
 2: 72
 3: 1

My hunch is that another 4 "T"s might be disposed of by creating a more efficient boundary layer at the edge. The other answer may provide clues how to do this. The bulk solution for the main section of the board cannot be improved upon.
This is the resulting distribution mocked up in Excel as a scratchpad:

Pieces belonging to the main tiling heuristic are capital "T" and coloured green in the bulk and have all their adjacent squares perfectly covered. "T"s near the edges are pink because they have at least one wasted attack. The extra additions to fixup the boundary are lower case "t". I think it might be possible to do better so I offer this pattern in the hope that an optimiser starting from here can find a better way to optimise the edges. My intuition has pretty much run out of steam at this point. A hybrid of this and the other answer will probably do better.
